# PyTorch returns a "Dataset Not found" error

Tags: python, pytorch, training-data, yolo, yolov5

I am trying to train a dataset locally using yolov5 but it keeps throwing "Dataset not found" exceptions I also tried changing the paths to absolute paths but it still throws the exception.

```
C:\yolov5>python train.py --img 416 --batch 24 --epochs 1000 --data C:\yolov5\data\data.yaml --cfg C:\yolov5\models\yolov5l.yaml --weights '' --name yolov5l_results  --cache
train: weights='', cfg=C:\yolov5\models\yolov5l.yaml, data=C:\yolov5\data\data.yaml, hyp=data\hyps\hyp.scratch-low.yaml, epochs=1000, batch_size=24, imgsz=416, rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, noval=False, noautoanchor=False, noplots=False, evolve=None, bucket=, cache=ram, image_weights=False, device=, multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, optimizer=SGD, sync_bn=False, workers=8, project=runs\train, name=yolov5l_results, exist_ok=False, quad=False, cos_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, patience=100, freeze=[0], save_period=-1, local_rank=-1, entity=None, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, artifact_alias=latest
github: up to date with https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5
YOLOv5  v6.1-196-g614ef11 Python-3.10.4 torch-1.11.0+cpu CPU

hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.5, cls_pw=1.0, obj=1.0, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0
Weights & Biases: run 'pip install wandb' to automatically track and visualize YOLOv5  runs (RECOMMENDED)
TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs\train', view at http://localhost:6006/

Dataset not found , missing paths ['C:\\valid\\images']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\yolov5\train.py", line 670, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "C:\yolov5\train.py", line 565, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "C:\yolov5\train.py", line 107, in train
    data_dict = data_dict or check_dataset(data)  # check if None
  File "C:\yolov5\utils\general.py", line 502, in check_dataset
    raise Exception(emojis('Dataset not found ❌'))
Exception: Dataset not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The path you are mentioning might be incorrect.

Check your `.yaml` file

Mine look something this

```
train: ../OID/dataset/images/train  # train images (relative to 'path') 1742289 images
val: ../OID/dataset/images/val   # val images (relative to 'path') 80000 images

# no of classes
nc: 1

# class name
names: ['license plate']
```